# Detecting VoIP Calls from command line - Wireshark

Tags: sip, voip, wireshark, tshark

I'm using Wireshark to sniff the network and detect the VoIP calls. Detected VoIP calls can be seen from GUI (Telephony->VoIP Calls).

Now I want to get this list from command line. I searched through wireshark documents, but couldn't find a command to do that.

I'm using the commands like

```
tshark -r myFile -R "sip.CSeq.method eq INVITE"
```

from this topic : 
[Filtering VoIP calls with tshark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606961/filtering-voip-calls-with-tshark)

Is there a command to show that voip call list from command line, or do i have to parse the outputs and create my own list? Do you suggest any other tool to do that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want as the output? I suspect you will need to do some post-processing to get higher level info.

Comment: I want to create a list as the output including these fields of each SIP conversation just like in GUI : From, To, Initial Speaker, Start Time, Stop Time, State.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any way to coax `tshark` to give you what the Wireshark GUI does. You can do this by post-processing the output from `tshark`, but it will be a fair amount of work. One approach would be to:

- Have `tshark` to display the full details of the SIP packets (e.g., with `-v`)
- Pipe this to a process that will extract info from each packet. This process will need to detect packet boundaries, since the input will have multiple lines per packet.
- This process will need to store selected info from these packets (such as From, To, Start Time, etc.) and correlate this info across packets based on dialog identifiers.
- The process will need to understand the SIP protocol well enough to determine when calls are confirmed, terminated, etc.

This is certainly doable, but I wanted you to know what you are getting into.

An alternative to a separate process (that I have no experience with) is to write a [Wireshark script in Lua](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua), and invoke that via `tshark -Xlua_script:my_script.lua` (using a version of tshark compiled with Lua support). An example to help you get started can be found [here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Examples) under the example "Dump VoIP calls into separate files" (or similarly [here on Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/wiresharkplugin/source/browse/trunk/wsDatabase/voip_mysql.lua)). The advantages are:

- You automatically have access to the parsed SIP message.
- It is easy to tell where the packet begins and ends.
- Everything runs in a single process.

For me, the downside is that I would have to learn a new language (not the worst thing in the world).

EDIT: Looks like the SIP dissector in wireshark/tshark can help quite a bit if you use the Lua script approach; for instance, you can inspect `sip.response-request` on a SIP response to find the packet number of matching request.